# Bootstrap 4 $(...).load is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a page using Bootstrap 4 as basis. Since I'm new to Bootstrap it's a bit of trial-and-error.
I want to use some buttons to load separate php-files into a DIV using jQuery / javascript. The files to load are in place and the javascript is executed, but it stops where I use the .load() function: there I receive the error: "TypeError: $(...).load is not a function".
There are several reports on SO, but I seem not to be able to find the right solution.

Header:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Time Tracker<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['userrealname'])) ? " ::: ".$_SESSION['userrealname'] : ""; ?></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <!-- link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

My buttons:

```
<div class="container">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="overview">Overview</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="newcard">New Timecard</button>
```

The DIV to replace:

```
    <div id="contents">

    <?php

    //include('inc/overview.php');

    ?>
</div>
```

And the bottom of my HTML:

```
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/crypto.js"></script>
    <script src="js/user.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $( "#overview" ).click(function(){
                alert("OK");
                $( "#contents" ).load("inc/overview.php");
            });

            $( "#newcard" ).click(function(){
                $( "#contents" ).html("<strong>test</strong");
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The alert("OK") works fine (added to test), but the next line $( "#contents" ).load("inc/overview.php"); causes the error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery slim doesn't have the `load()` function. You have to use the full version.

Comment: Thank you Alex, that is sth I wasn't aware of. Replaced with the full version and it works! Now I need to wait 7 minutes until I can mark your reply as the accepted answer...

Comment: I didn't know it either, but I noticed you were using the slim version and searched it :)

Comment: DUUUUUDE! Thank you, @Alex! I was beating my head against the wall for days trying to figure this out. I'm so grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Just like Alex said, use the full JQuery. 
I also recommend to avoid any further problem using :

```
var {insert name here} = JQuery.noConflict()
```